# Azure DevOPs YAML based multi-stage pipeline APPROVAL using REST API (APPPROVALID for Release stage)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to programmatically approve the DevOps YAML based pipeline using REST API? I looked around found some APIs but not sure if supported for YAML pipelines.
Does anyone know how we can get the APPROVALID for a release in azure devops that we can use in the REST API call to Update the APPROVAL status?
Following is the REST API which can be called for APPROVAL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Unfortunately I have not even able to get all the Releases listed waiting for approval using the following REST API (approvals):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Any help on how to retrieve the ApprovalID for pending Release (stage in the YAML pipeline) so that we can approve it using the REST API.

Thank you